# Is there a limit to twitter accounts you can register in iOS?

Tags: ios, twitter

I am trying to implement login with twitter in my app. I want the user to choose which twitter account he wants to login with. So I want to know if there is a limit to twitter accounts one can register in the Settings app, so that I can decide on the UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not just let the app use the accounts stored inside twitter client ?

I have 7 twitter accounts stored with twitter client and i can use anyone of them with any Iphone App